# Encoding value as a signed short integer with limited memory space

Tags: c, encoding, hex

I have a question in the book about hexadecimal value that uses limited memory space

"Encode 1234 as a signed short integer with 2 bytes memory size
Let the following figure represents the 2 bytes memory space for the value.
Fill in the blanks with suitable binary values in Hexadecimal format"

The given answer was 0x04 and 0x??

This was how I thought I could solve the problem. Since we have 2 bytes instead of 4 bytes, I divided 1234 to "12" and "34" and converted them into ascii value, 0x0C and 0x22, which did not match given answer "0x04 and ..." above. Am I wrong in this approach? Am I missing something?

Comment: What you've tried is binary coded decimal. Doing any mathematics would be difficult.  
What I think you're being asked for is to just binary encode it. The answer that is being sought is probably 0x04D2 which is the direct hex representation of the number. based on the binary 00000100 11010010.

Comment: 2 Bytes means total 16 bits and 1 hex number require 4 bits of memory. Here you can represent the number as 0x04D2. You can see on paper that first bit of the number is 0 means it is positive.

Comment: There is no "encoding" going on here, if you do `uint16_t x = 0x4d2;` you could just as well do `uint16_t x = 1234;` and have the exact same result in memory. It's just a 16-bit unsigned integer, the base you use for the literal in the source code has no relation to what ends up in the bits of the memory at runtime. There is no such thing as a "hex value", the value can be *shown* as hex, but the value can't *be* hex.

Comment: Repeatedly divide the number by 16, retaining the remainders. The remainders give you the hexadecimal digits working from right to left.

Comment: Give the figure too. Give the whole question